# SharePoint 2007: Target Audience for Link Lists items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0, sharepoint-list

I created a Link List where each item has a specific target audience from the Active Directory group assigned. I added this link list on a page as a webpart. I am trying to get the user to ONLY be able to see the items on the list to which they have access to from the target audience field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activated Target Audience on the link list and used a Content Query Web Part with Target Audience so it would display the links to whom the user has access to.

[Teach the Content Query Web Part how to display a link list](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/01/teach-content-query-web-part-how-to.html)

Answer (score 1):

audience targeting isn't really security trimming, its security by obscurity. What you're looking for is item level security.

Comment: The links are actually folders on another server and they have their own security. I just want the user to see what they have access to.

Comment: Filter if you will, as opposed to seeing all the items in the link list to which they do not have access to. Found this, but doesn't seem to be showing anything. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-content-to-specific-audiences-HA010169053.aspx#BMstep1

Comment: Judging by the page you linked to, it suggests using a cqwp instead of a lists web part. Have you tried that?

Comment: Like I said, tried creating a content query web part pointing to the LINK list, but nothing showed up.